# Stream Analytics - Adding a newline in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, newline, azure-stream-analytics

I am setting a real time pipeline between Stream Analytics and calling Azure Machine Learning for making a prediction.

My issue is the model has different number of input and output rows so I am combining all events and then sending as a string into AML. 
( using collect () function and then apply JSON.stringify over collected events)

[{"list":"[{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:22:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1907,\"var2\":1925,\"var3\":1951},{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:23:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1924,\"var2\":1978,\"var3\"2017}]"}]

For it to be parsed in AML via a web service we need to add a fixed string and new line like

**JSON_str**

[{"list":"[{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:22:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1907,\"var2\":1925,\"var3\":1951},{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:23:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1924,\"var2\":1978,\"var3\"2017}]"}]

such that it gets interpreted as a new row of data and the fixed string will always be interpreted as a header .

I have tried all combinations of

str1= 
[{"list":"[{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:22:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1907,\"var2\":1925,\"var3\":1951},{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:23:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1924,\"var2\":1978,\"var3\"2017}]"}]

new str= "JSON_STR" + "\r\n" + Str1

but it gets added as plain text(\r\n) and not as newline.

Expected Inputin AML:
( Please ignore change in column names as I had simplified the variable list when adding question.
But basically I trained the model assuming a column name and having 1 row of data]
http://i67.tinypic.com/16izi29.jpg

Will really appreciate your help as I feel I am missing something specific to Stream Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on my side, and ‘\r\n’ creates a new line as expected when you use JavaScript in Azure Stream Analytics.

However, you may want to be sure to use a text visualizer to see the formatted text. Looking at the raw data will still show \r\n.

Thanks!

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was looking at the raw output which showed \r\n.  But one question I still have is that on converting the output in needed format for AML. The way I have trained the AML model is to expect 1 row and 1 column as input data. With column header as string header and row value as the data( attached picture above).

Answer (score 0):

There are some issue in your json string.

1. Missing symbol `:` in the string `\"var3\"2017`, it should be `\"var3\":2017`.
2. The `list` property value `"[{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:22:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1907,\"var2\":1925,\"var3\":1951},{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:23:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1924,\"var2\":1978,\"var3\"2017}]"` is not a valid json array, just a string, So you need to convert it as below.

   ```
   str1= [{"list":"[{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:22:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1907,\"var2\":1925,\"var3\":1951},{\"date\":\"2017-03-31T06:23:00.0000000Z\",\"var1\":1924,\"var2\":1978,\"var3\":2017}]"}]
   str1 = str1.replace('"[','[').replace(']"',']')
   ```

Then you can parse it as json object via `var json1 = JSON.parse(str)` and stringify the json object to string var `var str1 = JSON.stringify(json1)`.

Hope it helps.